# @Size Validator is not working in my Spring Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi i am trying to put validation in my spring project but it is not working for me i also add all the required validator jar in my lib folder.

**My Controller Class is looking like**

```
package qm;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class StudentAdmissionController {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setDisallowedFields(new String[] {"studentSkill","studentDOB"});
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class,"studentDOB", new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/registration.html",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getStudentAdmissionForm() {
        ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("AdmissionForm");

        return model;
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addCommonObject(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("headerMessage","Q-Manager.com");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/submit-detail.html",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView studentDetail(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student1") Student student,BindingResult result) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("AdmissionForm");
            return model;
        }       
        ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("AdmissionSuccess");
        return model;

    }


}
```

**my Student Class is**

```
package qm;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Student {

    @Size(min=2,max=30)
    private String studentName;

    private String studentHobby;
    private Long studentMobile;
    private Date studentDOB;
    private ArrayList<String> studentSkill;
    private Address studentAddress;

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }
    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }
    public String getStudentHobby() {
        return studentHobby;
    }
    public void setStudentHobby(String studentHobby) {
        this.studentHobby = studentHobby;
    }
    public Long getStudentMobile() {
        return studentMobile;
    }
    public void setStudentMobile(Long studentMobile) {
        this.studentMobile = studentMobile;
    }
    public Date getStudentDOB() {
        return studentDOB;
    }
    public void setStudentDOB(Date studentDOB) {
        this.studentDOB = studentDOB;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getStudentSkill() {
        return studentSkill;
    }
    public void setStudentSkill(ArrayList<String> studentSkill) {
        this.studentSkill = studentSkill;
    }
    public Address getStudentAddress() {
        return studentAddress;
    }
    public void setStudentAddress(Address studentAddress) {
        this.studentAddress = studentAddress;
    }


}
```

**my Address Class is**

```
package qm;

public class Address {

    private String country,city,street,pincode;

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getPincode() {
        return pincode;
    }

    public void setPincode(String pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }

}
```

**and Here is my AdmissionForm.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Student Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <center><h4>${headerMessage}</h4></center>
            <center><h4>Student Admission Form</h4></center>
            <center>
                <form:errors path="student1.*"/>
            </center>
            <form action="submit-detail.html" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                        <td>Student Name</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="studentName"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Hobby</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="studentHobby"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Student Mobile</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="studentMobile"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>DOB</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="studentDOB" value="May 04 09:51:52 CDT 2009"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Skills</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="studentSkill" multiple>
                                <option value="Core java">Core java</option>
                                <option value="Spring Core">Spring Core</option>
                                <option value="Spring MVC">Spring MVC</option>
                            </select>   
                        </td>
                </tr>


            </table>



            <table>

                <tr><td>Student Address</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Country<input type="text" name="studentAddress.country"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>City<input type="text" name="studentAddress.city"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Street<input type="text" name="studentAddress.street"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Pin Code<input type="text" name="studentAddress.pincode"/></td></tr>

                <tr>    
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
                </tr>

            </table>


            </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

anyone suggest me the where i am wrong so i will correct my code actually in my previous research i found that most of the people suggest regarding the jars ie need so i define all the required jars for validation in spring.

1. classmate-1.0.0 jars
2. hibernate-validator-annotation-processor-5.1.2.Final jar
3. jboss-logging-3.1.3.ga jar
4. validation-api-1.1.0.final

I used Spring 4.3.* jars for this project

Comment: What isn't working...

Comment: @Size validation in Student.java class  @Size(min=2,max=30)

Comment: What isn't working about that... Just telling something doesn't work isn't going to help. What are you trying to do and what do you expect to happen. What is your input...

Comment: actually i am trying to validate studentName should be min 2 character and maximum 30 character but when i try to run the application it doesnot validate it simply goes on studentSuccess.jsp page.

Comment: what value it isn't validating.. @Size ignores `null` so if you don't provide any value it is valid with respect to the `@Size` annotation. But your information is incomplete and it is hard to guess what you try to validate. The only thing you tell is it doesn't work. Please be more specific in which cases it doesn't work.

Comment: when i give simply 1 character or trying to give more than 30 character it was not giving me any error. and simply go on AdmissionSuccess.jsp

Comment: Use the Spring form tags to define your fields and form. Currently you aren't doing that.

Comment: Also it does work the problem is you are destroying the model. Instead of the `ModelAndView` return a `String` with only the view name.

Answer (score 1):

Try by adding below dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Provide more information on rationale behind using hibernate-validator.

Comment: the import is javax.validation.constraints.Size; this has nothing to do with hibernate

Answer (score 0):

you need to add mvc annotation tag in spring dispatcher.

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```